# jQuery served from Google's CDN seems to have bad expires headers

Tags: jquery, cdn

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js

```
Age:538083
Cache-Control:public,max-age=31536000
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:33321
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 23 Nov 2011 17:39:54 GMT
Expires:Wed, 23 Nov 2011 17:39:54 GMT                  <-- very strange
Last-Modified:Thu, 10 Nov 2011 18:58:43 GMT
Server:sffe
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Today is Nov 29, so why do I get "expires" header from 6 days ago?

Comment: The `Expires` in the past is not as interesting as the `Date` in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks that way!

Notice that they've set the ***Cache-Control: max-age*** parameter, which will override the Expires header in any browser that supports HTTP/1.1, so don't fret too much!